# Flask Returning Invalid CSRF when run via Docker

Tags: docker, rest, flask, cors, csrf

I have a flask app, and through one of it's routes I am making a call to another endpoint.

When I run the app, via `flask run` the API requests which I send (via Postman) to the endpoint are getting successfully decoded.

However, when I docker run the same thing, and use API requests (via Postman) to decode, it returns

```
    "error": "INVALID_CSRF"
```

Error content also states, that this was due to a session being ended.

My *app.py* implementation in flask is as follows.

```
@app.route("/decode", methods=["POST"])
def decode():
  # API call to the third party endpoint goes here
  # return response
```

Please note that I am making use of CORS from *flask_cors*